# Textfield delegate swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

currently I am trying to detect when a textield gets tapped.
So I am having multiple textfields and if one of them gets the focus then I want to call a function.
Currently I tried it with this code:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField!) {    //delegate method
    print("Test")
}
```

But this only works if the user starts writing. I want to print something if the textfield gots the focus (its getting tapped).

Does somebody know how to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this function

```
  func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
{
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this push a notification if the user stops writing?

Comment: Check the edit i posted the wrong function earlier :)